# How to have an AND condition in HAVING clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 4 tables in a database, namely `employee_details_table (emp_no, emp_name, dept_no)`, `department_table (dept_no, dept_name)`, `grade_table (grade_id, grade_name)` and `relation_table (emp_no, grade_id)`.

The scenario of database structure is:
I need to get the `emp_name` and `dept_name` of all employees whose `(grade_id = 1 AND grade_id = 2 AND grade_id = 3)`, i.e. employees with all the 3 `grade_id`. (Note: There can be employees without `grade_id`.)

My MySQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT( grade_id ) AS gradeid
  FROM employee_details_table t1
  LEFT JOIN department_table t2
    USING ( dept_no )
  LEFT JOIN relation_table t3
    USING ( emp_no )
  LEFT JOIN grade_table t4
    USING ( grade_id )
  GROUP BY t1.emp_no
  HAVING grade_id = '1' OR grade_id = '2' OR grade_id = '3';
```

For the above query I get all the rows as output. I also tried using `AND` instead of `OR` but I don't get any output. I have used `WHERE IN (1,2,3)`. I get the rows with `1 OR 2 OR 3` as `grade_id`. `WHERE IN(1 AND 2 AND 3)` does not work

Please help me correct the query.

Comment: Well the grade_id can't have multiple values in a single row, can it?

Comment: no it cant have multiple values in one row but one employee can have 2 or more grade_id. So i need employees who have grade_id 1 AND 2 AND 3

Comment: does HAVING grade_id like '%1%' AND grade_id LIKE '%2%' AND grade_id LIKE '%3%' work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should do the trick:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT( grade_id ) AS gradeid
  FROM employee_details_table t1
  LEFT JOIN department_table t2
    USING ( dept_no )
  LEFT JOIN relation_table t3
    USING ( emp_no )
  LEFT JOIN grade_table t4
    USING ( grade_id )
  WHERE grade_id IN ('1','2','3')
  GROUP BY t1.emp_no
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT grade_id) = 3;
```

First, take all employees that have at least one grade within the interesting ones (1, 2 and 3), then keep only the employees that have exactly three different grades, which indirectly means they have all three of them. If you want your `group_concat` to have all grades (including those that are not 1, 2 or 3), you'll need to mess around with a subquery, or do some nice magic with an "IF" statement in the HAVING clause. I can give a sample of this if you like.